# apt-get 404'ing on update

Tags: apt

I recently updated everything on my system to the testing branch of Debian because my laptop didn't like the 3.2.0-4 kernel. After updating, `apt-get update` stopped working for some reason I can't figure out.

Here's the output:

```
root@pdebian:/home/phanta# apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates InRelease           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                    
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates Release.gpg          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                        
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates Release              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources/DiffIndex         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex  
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:1 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing InRelease                     
Ign ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing InRelease                                         
Get:2 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates InRelease                               
Ign ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates InRelease                                 
Get:3 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release.gpg                                     
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release.gpg                                       
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:4 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates Release.gpg                             
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates Release.gpg                               
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:5 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release                                         
Ign ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release                                           
Get:6 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates Release                                 
Ign ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates Release                                   
Get:7 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Sources                                    
Get:8 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages                             
Get:9 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages                         
Get:10 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                             
Err http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main Sources                           
  404  Not Found
Get:11 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                           
Get:12 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                           
Get:13 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                               
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main Translation-en     
Err http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main amd64 Packages     
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                      
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages               
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Get:14 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en_US      
Err http://security.debian.org testing/updates/main i386 Packages         
  404  Not Found
Get:15 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en            
Get:16 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Sources
Get:17 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:18 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:19 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en_US
Get:20 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en
Get:21 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Sources 
Get:22 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages
Get:23 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages
Get:24 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Get:25 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Get:26 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en_US
Get:27 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en
Get:28 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en_US
Get:29 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en
Get:30 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Sources
Get:31 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:32 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:33 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en_US
Get:34 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en
Get:35 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Sources  
Get:36 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages
Get:37 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages
Get:38 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages
Get:39 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages
Get:40 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Get:41 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en
Get:42 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en  
Get:43 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en
Get:44 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Sources
Get:45 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:46 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:47 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en_US
Get:48 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en
Get:49 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Sources
Get:50 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages
Get:51 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages
Get:52 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages
Get:53 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages
Get:54 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en_US
Get:55 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en
Get:56 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en_US
Get:57 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en
Get:58 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Sources
Get:59 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:60 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:61 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en_US
Get:62 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en
Get:63 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Sources
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Sources
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:64 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:65 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:66 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:67 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:68 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en_US
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:69 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main Translation-en
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:70 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en_US
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en_US
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:71 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:72 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Sources
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Sources
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:73 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:74 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main i386 Packages
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main i386 Packages
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:75 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en_US
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
Get:76 ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en
Err ftp://ftp.us.debian.org testing-updates/main Translation-en
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/testing/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/byteit101/frc-toolchain/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/byteit101/frc-toolchain/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/testing/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/byteit101/frc-toolchain/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/testing/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/Release.gpg  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/source/Sources  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-updates/main/source/Sources  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/testing-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Error: No such file or directory.  '

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm unsure of why it 404's, because I can download the files from an ftp client or web browser without trouble.

EDIT: Here's my sources.list:

```
deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main

deb ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main
deb-src ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main
```

Comment: Paste your `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question, please. Is networking still functioning? Why on earth do you have `ftp` sources in there? That isn't standard these days.

Comment: I have no idea why I use ftp sources - I set up the sources.list a while ago, and I forgot what I was thinking.

Comment: Is it `testing/updates` or `testing-updates`? You have both.

Comment: It looks like `testing/updates` seems to be working...? It's odd because `testing-updates` is a real dir on the ftp server, although `testing/updates` is not.

Comment: APT sometimes has hash mismatches for me that can break updates.  While this is a different symptom, perhaps it has the same solution:  make sure you're not running anything apt-related (check with `ps auxw |grep '\bapt'`) and then run `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: No, I still get the massive block of 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, never mind. As it turns out I just managed to make a mess out of my `nsswitch.conf` and it broke name resolving. There never was a problem with apt-get.